# Integrated camera or built-in camera problem

Tags: 23.04

I was doing the single boot before few days ago.
Why is detected my built-in or integrated camera in cheese app and also showing no device found and in the privacy section camera option is not showing.
So how to enable my camera.
My laptop model is Acer aspire 7 12th gen core i5.
And ubuntu version is 23.04.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the output of `lsusb`? Also, do `sudo apt install v4l-utils` and run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to make a list of devices. Include that in your question.